# How to create input HOC components correctly?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a component that accumulates the number of characters

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";

export const withAccumulate = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class ControlCharsInput extends Component {

        static propTypes = {
            accumulate: PropTypes.number,
            afterAccumulate: PropTypes.func.isRequired
        };

        static defaultProps = {
            accumulate: 0
        };

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        onInputChange = (e) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            if(value.length > 0 && value.length < this.props.accumulate){
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            this.props.afterAccumulate(value);
        };

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent onChange={this.onInputChange}/>;
        }
    };
};
```

But the onChange method will never be called
What's my mistake?
Used

```
const SomeInput = props => (<input className=.../>)
const InputAccumulate = withAccumulate(SomeInput);
```

I  also thought that if you get rid of HOC and make a simple wrapper component.
But then I pass props to input and props from the wrapper and get warnings

```
render () {     // here props combined with afterAccumulate etc
 return (<input {...props} onChange={this.onChange}>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to pass props down to the actual input in your `SomeInput` component:

```
const SomeInput = (props) => (<input {...props}/>)
```

Here is your fixed [component](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwwdqY).